# Hex String to Image

Tags: java, string, image, io

I have a hex string which looks like:

```
String hexImage ="0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010200006400640000FFEC00114475636B79000100040000003C..."
```

Which I need to convert to an image using Java. I've tried converting to a byte array first with  org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex class. FileOutputStream later dumps this to a file.

```
char[] charArr= hexImage.toCharArray();
byte[] byteArray = Hex.decodeHex(charArr);
```

however the parser in the Hex class chokes, with an Decoder exception :  Odd number of characters. No matter what method I use to convert to a byte array, it fails. The fileformat is definitely a JPEG.

I've tried removing <strike>this</strike> 0xFF from the string, but the image is corrupt at this point. 0xFF I assume is a the culprit - anyone any ideas on what do I need to do to correct this?

Comment: What `THIS` have you tried removing?

Comment: Perhaps the cuprit is that you have an odd number of characters as the error message suggests.  Have you checked this?  Does the Hex method expect you to start with `0x`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey good point on whether string should start with `0x`, however these are 2 chars, therefore the OP still has a problem with the initial string.

Comment: To start with FFD8 is OK for a JPEG/JIFF. It is the code of "Start of Image"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, each byte is represented by 2 hex digits, therefore, if you have an odd number of digits in your HEX string, then something is wrong with it.  You can try padding it with 0 in the beginning, such as this:

```
String hexImage ="0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010200006400640000FFEC00114475636B79000100040000003C...";
if(hexImage.length()%2 == 1)
    hexImage = "0x0" + hexImage.substring(2);
```

or at the end, such as this:

```
String hexImage ="0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010200006400640000FFEC00114475636B79000100040000003C...";
if(hexImage.length()%2 == 1)
    hexImage += "0";
```

However this is not guaranteed to produce a proper image.

On the whole, you should check how you get your hex string.  A proper byte sequence should always contain an even number of hex digits.

**EDIT:** In addition, as Peter Lawrey indicated in his comment, you should check whether the `decode` method expects `0x` in front of the string.

Comment: The String comes direct from SQL server, however its a representation of an Image data type (BLOB) - which I should probably re-examine in my program! Your second paragraph made me double check. Missed that this wasn't just a string of characters..which is how it looks when you copy from table directly.

Answer (score 0):

for even length string

```
 public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String str) {
    try {


        String s = str;
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            if (i == len - 1) {
                 System.out.println("in correct");                   
            } else {

                data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                        + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));


            }
        }
        return data;
    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException sex) {

        writeDirtyData(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(",")));
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Non of Odd hex string is correct**. Check source from you get this string . It is because of truncation of string due to limit no of characters. 
**If String is image is stored in database then retrieve it using program not using any tools**

I was having same problem with .net and MSSQL and by using webservice and Java Client
I tried all conversion and library including axis and util jpg.