# JAVA Converting Hexadecimal String

Tags: java, python, hex, decode, codec

In Python, I can convert hex to something like this..

```
s = "6025ce2069c61b15d8314f7cdd76b850dcd339547335d0e4a1e0b9915b0230cd"

s.decode('hex')
'`%\xce i\xc6\x1b\x15\xd81O|\xddv\xb8P\xdc\xd39Ts5\xd0\xe4\xa1\xe0\xb9\x91[\x020\xcd'
```

My question is how to do the same thing in Java?

I did this in Java like this but it raises an exception.

```
new String(Hex.decodeHex(str.toCharArray()), "UTF-8"
```

The error messege is like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException: Odd number of characters.
```

========================================================

I removed UTF-8 but I am still getting the same exception.. please help!

```
new String(Hex.decodeHex(combined.toCharArray()))

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException: Odd number of characters.
```

Comment: The error message is clear enough.

Comment: The hex data you have there is *not UTF-8 data*. The Python code never tries to interpret the bytes as a text encoding, all you have is bytes still.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi so how to do the same thing in Java?

Comment: Your `combined` variable - what does it contain?

Comment: Please checkout the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143135/hex-string-to-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, DecoderException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String hexString = "6025ce2069c61b15d8314f7cdd76b850dcd339547335d0e4a1e0b9915b0230cd";
        byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(hexString.toCharArray());
        System.out.println(new String(bytes , "UTF-8"));
    }
```

**Output**

```
`%? i??1O|?v?P??9Ts5???[0?
```

Comment: Conclusion: the OP doesn't have the data in `hexString` that they think they have.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `hexString.matches("-?[0-9a-fA-F]+")` return true, refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424540/verify-if-string-is-hexadecimal)

Comment: What does that have to do with the fact that the OP does not have an even number of hex digits in their input? And allowing a `-` at the start will only make matters worse, not better.