# Open Text From a Given Offset (Java)

Tags: java, hex, offset

I am trying to make a Java program to edit some text stored in offsets of a .bin file (the file is **hexadecimal**, yet it is a .bin file). Here is my class that attempts this:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import java.io.*;

public class Class{
    public static String getOffsetText(String offset, File bin){
        String txt = null;
        try{
            byte[] off = Hex.decodeHex(offset.toCharArray());
            txt = new String(off, "UTF-8");
        }catch(DecodeException | UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return txt;
    }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException: Illegal hexadecimal character x at index 1
    at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.toDigit(Hex.java:178)
    at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.decodeHex(Hex.java:91)
```

1st Note: my class with the main method just tries to use this method in a GUI. Also, Eclipse is not showing that my code has any errors or warnings.

2nd Note: The .bin files I have may be encrypted, but I am not entirely sure that they are.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems your function does not need to receive the file since it only calculates the offset.

I believe that the problem is that the offset string is of the form "0x12346" ... , so when it tries to decode x it fails as it is not a digit. 
I'd suggest you check if the string starts with 0x,if so remove them and parse the rest as hexa

Comment: Now it gives me another error: `org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException: Odd number of characters.
 at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.decodeHex(Hex.java:82)`

Comment: There's an answer to that in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/a/10143209/6372296

Comment: All right! There are no errors now. However, the text box that is supposed to have the text is always empty. Even when I try to change the offset.